# NSTableView always has some intercell spacing when drawing

Tags: macos, nstableview, nsimage

I have an NSTableView, but I am not displaying it directly in a window.  I instead show an NSImageView in front of it, and draw all or part of the table view (actually, part of its containing scroll view, but I will continue to say table view) into an image which the NSImageView displays. Everything worked fine initially.  I then added the ability to draw only part of the table view into the image, to get a zoom effect.  For example, while the image view and its image are always 500x500, a 200x200 square of the table view may be drawn into the image (scaled up by the method doing the drawing). My issue is that, when the pixels in the table view map at >1:1 to pixels in the image view, I see white intercell spaces from the table view.

I draw part of the table view like so:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [scrollViewContainingTableView bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:visibleImageRect];
[imageRep setSize:imgSize];
[scrollViewContainingTableView cacheDisplayInRect:rectIWantFromTableView toBitmapImageRep:imageRep];
```

I thought my table cell drawing logic may be wrong, so I drew black over the entire view and the white inter-row lines remain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtDGN.png

I do already set the inter-cell spacing to 0 with this method call:

`[tableView setIntercellSpacing:NSMakeSize(0, 0)];`

How can I completely eliminate these inter-row spaces?